# Finding basis of eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4 $ and $U,V$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that
$$ T|_{U} = \operatorname{Id} $$
$$ T|_{V} = -\operatorname{Id}  $$
$$ \operatorname{Null}(T-2\operatorname{Id}) = (U + V)^{\perp} $$
$$ \operatorname{rank}(T-2\operatorname{Id}) = 2$$

i) Determine a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ of eigenvectors of $T$.

ii) Show that $T$ is invertible.

If I'm not mistaken, the eigenvalues of $T$ are $1,-1$ and $2$ with multiplicity $2$. So $T$ is invertible. Now for the eigenvectors, am I supposed to find them explicitly? I think knowing a basis for $U,V$ and $(U + V)^{\perp}$ would resolve, but is there enough information to find them?

Comment: What can you say about the dimension of $U$? Does that make it easy to pick a basis for it?

Comment: Hmm... I believe $U$ and $V$ have both dimension $1$, while $(U + V)^{\perp}$ has 2. So can I just pick one vector for the basis of $U$, another vector orthogonal to it for the basis of $V$ and then find/pick two perpendicular ones for the basis of $(U + V)^{\perp}$ ? But how would I make sure these last vectors have eigenvalue $2$?

Answer (score 0):

Since the rank of $T-2\mathrm{id}$ is $2$, also its nullity is $2$, which means that $\dim(U+V)^\perp=2$ and so $\dim U+V=2$.

Clearly, $U\cap V=\{0\}$, because for $x\in U\cap V$ you have $T(x)=x$ and $T(x)=-x$.

This leaves the cases: $\dim U=1=\dim V$; $\dim U=0$ and $\dim V=2$; $\dim U=2$ and $\dim V=0$.

In all three cases, taking a basis of $U$ and $V$ will provide a basis of $U+V$; its orthogonal complement is by assumption the eigenspace relative to $2$.

Comment: But it isn't possible to find such a basis explicitly, is it? I can't just pick any basis for, say, $U$ and $V$ then find the orthogonal complement, right?

Comment: @krs1997 Without explicit information on $T$, you can't show a basis.